# How to allow using javascript in RichHtmlField control?

Tags: html, sharepoint

Is it possible to set up RichHtmlField control to allow javascript in HTML?
I mean I need to insert some script into field content, but the code is removed from source after submit.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way of inserting javascript into the RichHtmlField. Usually in this situation, the following options are available:

a) If you're just trying to get a piece of javascript anywhere on the page, you could insert a Content Editor Web Part. It allows you to insert javascript.

b) If you're stuck because you promised RichHtmlField javascript insertion to your client (or other common scenarios), you could purchase [Telerik RadEditor](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editoroverview.html).
It should get around the issue.

Hope this helps.